# Comparing string arrays for matching elements, keep missing elements in count

Tags: python

I have a function that takes a string, breaks it into an array of characters and then enumerates over it comparing it to a predefined list of elements and returning the total number of matching elements found.

The problem that I'm getting is that I only ever grab the first 3 or 4 matching elements and nothing beyond that and I'm not sure why.

Expected outcome:

```
string = "kkkwwwaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmxyz"

# Should return 6/60
# Instead returns 3/60
```

My function:

```
def split(word):
  return [char for char in word]


letters = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','x','y','z']

badLetters = letters[13:27]

stringArray = split(string)
stringArrayLength = len(stringArray)
matchingBadLetters = len([key for key, val in enumerate(badLetters) if val in set(stringArray)])

print({matchingBadLetters}/{stringArrayLength})
```

Comment: Try using a debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of iterating over `badLetters`, check whether or not each character in `string` exists in the subset of the alphabet that you have chosen (`badLetters`):

```
import string
s = "kkkwwwaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmxyz"
badLetters = string.ascii_lowercase[13:27]
print(f'{sum(i in badLetters for i in s)}/{len(s)}')
```

Output:

```
6/60
```

Answer (score 1):

you are simply missing a "w" in letters :)

You may use this instead for better readability:

```
import string
list(string.ascii_lowercase)
```

Comment: Wow that was it! Thank you so much!